# jQuery Mobile load markup from php - will not enhance markup 2nd time

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Creating app with jQuery Mobile, I want a page to load data from a server,  I'm building the list items in PHP when I load for various reasons.

So when I load a page for the first time everything goes smoothly, if I load it again the data reinserts but the markup doesn't enhance.

There are several threads on SO adress this EXACT issue, however the accepted answer is always use .trigger('create').  This I have done but I've had no success, **I've tried using .listview('refresh'), .trigger('updatelayout'), I've tried triggering these events on the page, the class for the page, the listview div, putting it in the complete: of my ajax call** but nothing. So I've resorted to asking you community:

I'm using jQM 1.1.1: Have I missed something if you require more Info I'll happily provide:

Here is my front page

```
<div data-role="page" id="frontPage">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="e" data-id="commonHead" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        <h1>
            myApp
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="content">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#" onClick="viewfList()">List</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the page to which I naviagate to:

```
<div data-role="page" id="fView">
    <div class="commonHeader"></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="fList">

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the viewfList function I use to call the page

```
function viewFeatList(){
    jQuery.ajax({ //getting my new <li>
            url: 'http://sources.mysource.com/get_list.php',
            type: 'POST',
            //data: myData,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){     
                $('#fList').empty(); //emptying the listview                
                for (i=0;i<data.f.length;i++){
                    $('#fList').append(data.f[i]); //appending the <li>
                    }
                $('#fList').trigger('create'); //this version's attempt to re-enhance markup
                $.mobile.changePage('#fView');   //navigate to page                         

                },
            error:  function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                myAlert('There was an error submitting your request')
                }
            });

    }
```

Comment: instead of triggering create call .listview("refresh");

Comment: As stated in the question I've already tried that along with .trigger('updatelayout'), I've tried triggering these events on the page, the class for the page, the listview div, putting it in the complete: of my ajax call. Because I won't discount anything I've just tried it again and it's not working out for me...on what jQuery object would you use that method?

Comment: sorry, missed that.  From what I can gather from your code you're building the list before changing page. so a refresh should be neccessary anyway.  Do you get any console errors?

Comment: No console errors, yes I agree a refresh should be necessary, however for a reason I cannot discern, I can't seem to trigger a page refresh...I your opinion am I triggering the event on the correct element?

Comment: did you trying call .page() on the page before it is shown?  this should initialise the whole page

Comment: Yes, I am seeing the same issue and an answer for this would help me as well. I tried all the above and it still doesn't enhance the markup

Comment: .page is deprecated in 1.1.1, I've solved it you were right about listview('refresh') and checking the console though but I was doing in on the wrong element in the wrong order I'll post my answer thanks...I'll +1 the comments for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to inspiration from the comments, and overcoming my own negligence due to frustration I've found a solution:

Here is my new function

```
function viewfList(){
    jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'http://sources.mysource.com/get_list.php',
            type: 'POST',
            //data: myData,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){     
                $('#fList').empty();;               
                for (i=0;i<data.f.length;i++){
                    $('#fList').append(data.f[i]);
                    }

                $.mobile.changePage('#fView');  
                $('#fList').listview('refresh');                                            
                },
            error:  function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                myAlert('There was an error submitting your request')
                }
            });

    }
```

Turns out .listview('refresh') did work and it did indeed throw out an error in the Javascript console according to [CrimsonChin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874927/crimsonchin)'s suggestions however I was executing these on the page not the actual listview element.  When I did execute it on the listview element I got this error:

> Uncaught cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'refresh'

Which led me, obviously, to call the refresh **after** the page had been changed to.

My only concern with this is: if there is alot to do on the page one day, is it possible I'll see un-enhanced markup flash on the screen for a split second before it changes...this doesn't happen now but i'm running a very basic page for the time being.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: thanks for the nod.  I'm pretty sure that once a listview has been initalised unstyled elements are hidden until the listview is refreshed.